# Problema Spring MVC + Maven + Bootstrap

Tags: css, bootstrap-3, maven, spring-mvc

Bom dia.
Estou tentando colocar bootstrap na index da minha aplicação mas não estou conseguindo, a index não lê os CSS.
Pesquisei na internet e pelo que eu entendi, o css deve ficar dentro da seguinte estrutura, src/main/webapp/resources.css/

```
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="/resources.css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

A estrutura está assim;
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: A resposta te ajudou a resolver a dúvida? É possível aceitá-la agora?

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa configurar o Spring para servir seus recursos estáticos. Isso pode ser feito programaticamente ou via XML.

### Classe de configuração Java

```
@Configuration
public class SpringConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {  

   ...

   @Override
   public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
       registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
   }

   @Override
   public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
       configurer.enable();
   }
}
```

### Servlet.xml

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/"/>
```

Comment: obrigado Murillo pelo retorno, tem algum exemplo de configuração programaticamente ?

Comment: É o exemplo com título Classe de configuração Java

Comment: ok, entendi, muito obrigado pela ajuda.